# Сборка зависимостей и билда

Tags: c#, msbuild

Есть десктоп решение (4.6 и net standard 2.0), в котором буквально три уровня зависимостей - шаредная сборка (ядро), UI сборка и плагин (точнее их несколько, но они одинаковые с точки зрения зависимостей).

UI сборка сделана зависимой от ядра, обычный билд успешно копирует сборки когда это нужно, исключая к сожалению нативные зависимости.
У плагинов всё ещё печальне, т.к. они зависят от ядра, но никто не должен о них знать, стандартными зависимостями не удается пользоваться.

Сейчас сборка гарантируется частично beforebuild событием, но т.к. несвязанные проекты могут компилироваться в разном порядке, иногда приходится тупо два раза билдить. Плюс, сейчас оно сделано с использованием xcopy, а хочется кроссплатформенную сборку.

Насколько я понял, есть вариант с targets файлами, но по ним не нашел никакой толковой справки, кроме например статьи https://rsdn.org/article/devtools/msbuild-05.xml#EVGAE

Плюс, есть разные вещи типа Cake (C# Make), но фактически это отдельный инструмент, которым придётся учиться пользоваться, плюс непонятно опять, насколько эти решения кроссплатформенные.

В целом - нужно какое то популярное решение, по которому есть хорошие доки и которое умеет в типовые решения (чтобы для билда проекта не пришлось писать вручную запуск msbuild) без костылей.

---

Примерная схема, как это сейчас выглядит. Сплошные линии - явные зависимости, пунктирные - которые подразумеваются, и которые приходится на костылях копировать из разных папок в разные папки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84389/discussion-on-question-by-monk----).

Comment: Из чата информации мало извлек. Если говорить о плагинах, то это не задача сборки, а часть некоторого процесса, назовем его "пре-релиз". Эта часть может быть покрыта MSBuild скриптом, а именно `target` с `copy` задачей, которая по условию копирует в файлы в bin\debug.

Comment: А если говорить о `Core` и его зависимостях, то он должен быть в отдельном решении и подключаться к UI через nuget пакет, тогда все файлы попадут в проект. Собственно плагины тоже следует вынести.

Comment: @UserName а разве зависимости проектные и nuget работают по разному? Всмысле, у меня и сейчас зависимые сборки из ядра в UI пробрасываются. Другое дело, есть некоторые зависимости, которые даже в ядро криво ставятся (проблема конкретных пакетов), их сейчас тупо руками копирую.

Comment: @Monk, посмотрел [эту статью про различные CI tools](https://www.g2crowd.com/categories/continuous-integration). Там много из чего выбирать, однако больше всего мне понравился [вариант EasyCIS](http://easycis.aspone.cz/home.aspx). Про него написано, что он для тех случаев когда необходимо быстрое решение без ощутимых временных затрат. Главное, сходу примерно понятно как им пользоваться, даже можно сделать на сайте [demo проект](http://easycis.aspone.cz/online-demo.aspx). Одна проблема, не знаю как безопасно скачать и установить. Частично спросил автора e-mail-ом. Есть какие-нибудь мысли?

Comment: Советую, все таки, освоить Cake. Он заявлен как кроссплатформенный, но не очень хорошо документирован, приходится смотреть исходники. Вряд ли, что то сравниться по гибкости. В нем у вас есть возможность полностью описать процесс и артефакты.

Comment: [Вот еще список вариантов](https://stackify.com/top-continuous-integration-tools/)

Comment: С некоторых пор "программирование" CI тулов считается не самым лучшим подходом. Лучший подход, это скрипт сборки, который делает все что вам нужно. А CI tool делает одну простую вещь - запускает ваш скрипт сборки и все. Это позволяет не только с легкостью менять CI, но и запускать и отлаживать сборку локально. Вот Cake, это тул для создания скриптов сборки.

Comment: @Alew, Спасибо, интересно узнать про скрипт!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге, msbuild закрыл все мои задачи, хоть местами и смотрится неудобно.

---

Для плагинов написан простой отдельный таргет:

```
<Project>
  <!-- Copy plugin dll and pdb files to shared folder after compile -->
  <Target Name="CopyAfterCompile" AfterTargets="CopyFilesToOutputDirectory">
    <ItemGroup>
      <SourceFiles Include="$(TargetPath)" />
      <SourceFiles Include="$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceFiles)" 
          DestinationFiles="@(SourceFiles->'$(ProjectDir)\..\Bin\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFramework)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  </Target> 
</Project>
```

Такой таргет потом легко подключается к проекту плагина по имени файла, как `<Import Project="..\Sites.props"/>` и автоматически копирует сборку в нужную папку.

ПС: отдельно стоит заметить, что я тут ссылаюсь на `TargetFramework`, но он работает только для мультитаргетных проектов, например мои сделаны под net461 и netstandard2.0

---

Приложения в netstandard я собираю как self-contained, и тут добавление сборок подцепилось только к событию "публикации", несмотря на кучу других советов в гугле. Выглядит примерно так:

```
  <!-- Copy native libs - skiasharp and sqlite interops -->
  <Target Name="CopyNativeLibraries" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <UserRoot>$(userprofile)</UserRoot>
      <UserRoot Condition="'$(userprofile)' == ''">$(HOME)</UserRoot>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Library Include="$(UserRoot)\.nuget\packages\skiasharp\1.57.1\runtimes\osx\native\libSkiaSharp.dylib" />
      <Library Include="$(UserRoot)\.nuget\packages\skiasharp\1.57.1\runtimes\win7-x64\native\libSkiaSharp.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Library)" 
          DestinationFiles="@(Library->'$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(PublishDir)'))\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  </Target>
```

На самом деле, разработчик skiasharp уже исправил публикацию своих сборок, но оно пока не вышло в релиз. А вот для sqlite интеропов обновление уже вышло, поэтому тут осталась только skia.

ПС: переменная UserRoot пытается определить папку, в которой находится нугет. Оно не совсем кроссплатформ, но Linux и Windows в текущей реализации работают.

---

В целом, для анализа порядка выполнения таргетов и анализа того, что кругом происходит, достаточно запустить `msbuild -v:diag` с билдом или публикацией. В логе будут записаны и все обработанные таргеты и их порядок. Большой плюс msbuild по сравнению с тем же Cake, который я вспоминал в вопросе - у него уже есть куча вычисленных переменных и ими просто надо пользоваться. Более того, у него и жизненный цикл вполне логичный (по логам) и накидать свой таргет, завязанный на существующий - довольно легко.